# npm init error - cannot create application

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Totally new to NodeJS

when trying to create a new application getting the following :
it does not create instead exits with a error log at the location

```
H:\app>npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (app)

H:\app>
```

Contents of error log :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'init' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.0
4 verbose stack Error: read EINVAL
4 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
4 verbose stack     at TTY.onread (net.js:568:26)
5 verbose cwd H:\app
6 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
7 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "init"
8 error node v6.11.0
9 error npm  v3.10.10
10 error code EINVAL
11 error errno EINVAL
12 error syscall read
13 error read EINVAL
14 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
14 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
15 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The first thing you should do is: read the log yourself. Even if you may not understand all the lines of the log... you could (1) get an idea what's wrong, (2) see a message like `use argument xy when z is not working` or as we have it here (3) see a line that clearly said where you should ask for help -> `If you need help, you may report this error at: <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>`

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47087759/getting-error-einval-invalid-argument-read-for-npm-install-save-dev-esli

Answer (score 0):

Try this command: `npm init - y`

By default the command above will create a default *package.json* at the current directory. It seems there is some problem regarding access. Once the default *package.json* file is created you can update it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Also new to NodeJS. I was unable to prompt the creation of a JSON file and even its questionnaire until I ran:

```
`npm init --yes`
```

neither: `npm init`, nor: `npm init --y`, worked for me. (I'm on Windows ).
Hope this helps newbies !