# getting "Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, read" for "npm install --save-dev eslint --verbose"

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native, npm-install

Any ideas/assistance here re how to get "npm install --save-dev eslint --verbose" working.  I keep getting:

```
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, read
```

I've setup up a new react-native project:

```
react-native init gcLists

E:\gcLists>npm -v
5.5.1
E:\gcLists>yarn -v
1.2.1
E:\gcLists>react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.5

npm install --save-dev eslint --verbose
```

Last part of the log:

```
npm http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/slice-ansi 104ms (from cache)
npm verb correctMkdir D:\Users\greg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using D:\Users\greg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-255cd84f0d76b150.lock for E:\gcLists\node_modules\.staging
npm info lifecycle semver@5.4.1~preuninstall: semver@5.4.1
npm info lifecycle semver@5.4.1~uninstall: semver@5.4.1
npm verb unbuild rmStuff semver@5.4.1 from E:\gcLists\node_modules
npm verb unlock done using D:\Users\greg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-255cd84f0d76b150.lock for E:\gcLists\node_modules\.staging
npm verb stack Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, read
npm verb stack     at D:\Users\greg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\gently-rm.js:275:7
npm verb stack     at D:\Users\greg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\iferr\index.js:13:50
npm verb stack     at D:\Users\greg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:287:18
npm verb stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
npm verb cwd E:\gcLists
npm verb Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm verb argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Users\\greg\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev" "eslint" "--verbose"
npm verb node v8.7.0
npm verb npm  v5.5.1
npm ERR! code EINVAL
npm ERR! EINVAL: invalid argument, read
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\greg\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-03T02_38_08_842Z-debug.log
```

Notes:

- On Windows 7

UPDATE:
* Results of `npm install --save-dev eslint --verbose` may be found [here.](https://pastebin.com/NcnpfpQ8)

Comment: Can you add environment variable `NODE_DEBUG=fs,module` and then run your installation? This will give a lot more log and something we can dig better into. Please create a pastebin of the log if it gets too large

Comment: ok - have to get back to you this evening on this...

Comment: @TarunLalwani just checking - will this work running react-native?  i.e. "react-native run-android"? where does this log then appear?

Comment: Do what you did earlier and got the error. This will basically show logs when npm command is executed

Comment: @TarunLalwani ok have run this with results here https://pastebin.com/NcnpfpQ8

Comment: can you try `yarn add cslint` instead? If you don't have yarn then install that first

Comment: Ok. Any debug flags to put on?. Issue seems to be with working on Windows is my feeling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158397/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-greg).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes some packages have issues with npm. This could be base on combination of  OS/package version/node version/npm version compatibility issue.

In such cases best thing is to do is try and use some other package manager. Try this with yarn

```
yarn add eslint
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, but it kinda sucks this is the best solution :'(

Comment: Though this works. I don't think it's good to accept as the best solution. The problem is with the node_modules file corruption. Not on the package manager.

Comment: yarn add eslint
Parsing scenario file add
ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'add'

Comment: That could be a different issue, I would suggest post a new question @sabertabatabaeeyazdi

Answer (score 16):

Since you are using drive letter E:, you might be on a portable drive. I had the same problem using an USB-Stick formatted on FAT32. I solved it reformatting to NTFS.

Comment: This was my problem, I've been working remotely a lot lately and had my development done on FAT32 USB Stick. Thanks!

Comment: I was using an external SSD formatted as exFAT and this was the problem.

Answer (score 8):

What helped me was to also delete my package-lock.json file.

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm i
```

Comment: In my case, that error occured after updating npm version. And as stated, this has solved the issue.

Comment: Solved my issue, way better than the suggested solution.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem happened to me and what i did was deleting the whole node_modules folder and run `npm install` again. It fixed the error. 
The reason was in the initial npm install it was closed in the middle by me which crashed some files.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the npm cache:

```
npm cache clean
```

Then try again.

Comment: tied "npm cache verify" and no luck unfortunately.  BTW from my terminal "As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead."

Comment: in order to make this work now you will need npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error when I did `npm update` so i deleted some `npm outdated` *node_modules* and ran `npm update` again and it worked.

`yarn upgrade` also fixed the thing.